# Server does not support Authenticated encryption (AEAD) cipher suites.(Windows server 2012 )

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2012, tls1.2

How to fix issues of "server does not support Authenticated encryption (AEAD) cipher suites" in ssl certificate and configuration on windows server 2012

Answer (score 2):

[SSL Labs - This server does not support Authenticated encryption (AEAD) cipher suites. Grade capped to B.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51658.ssl-labs-this-server-does-not-support-authenticated-encryption-aead-cipher-suites-grade-capped-to-b.aspx)

Short version: use an EC certificate, or add a registry key to bump up to 2048 bits.